# How to open a new window in python pygtk after clicking a button

Tags: python, pygtk

I'd like to know how to open a new window after clicking a button on current window.

I tried creating a list of objects of *gtk.Window()*

It gave me indexing error.

Comment: Create a new `gtk.Window` and make sure you store the reference somewhere in order to prevent its deletion by the garbage collector. For the specific problem with your list, please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm just at the beginning of working in pygtk too.

But, if you have other `gtk.Window()` in other file you have to do is like this:

```
btn.connect("clicked", self.onbtn1_clicked) #this is to connect to a function
```

Then you create a function like:

```
def onbtn1_clicked(self, widget):
       from yourscritp import classgtkwindow
       var1 = classgtkwindow()
       var1.show()
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English